# Why iAd not displaying in Dubai?

Tags: iphone, ios

In my [iPhone Application](http://www.facebook.com/iApppp) iAd displaying in many countries but not in Dubai, why its happening?

Comment: Questions about programming, development, and listing your apps on the App Store are off topic for Ask Different. While your wording sounds like you are a developer, end users might wonder the same thing, so the question is on-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple only delivers add to a few countries. Not Many.(U.S., Canada, Australia, New Zealand, Japan, France, Germany, Italy, Spain, and the U.K) Most likely, ad sales as low there or they do not have sales people there. So, if you plan to monetize your app, I'd suggest using a secondary ad network for the countries where iAd is not delivering ads.

Comment: which is the best secondary ad network?

Comment: The iAd Network has launched in Mexico too. follow this http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/2013/04/iad-vs-admob-clicks-fill-rate.html